# How to bind a DoubleProperty to an expression?

Tags: data-binding, properties, javafx-2, javafx

I have a DoubleProperty (`price`) and I want a second DoubleProperty (`discountedPrice`) to be bound to `price - 25%`.

So I thought I would use the `multiply` method but it does not seem to work as expected:

```
DoubleProperty price = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
DoubleProperty pctDiscount = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
pctDiscount.bind(price.multiply(0.75));

price.set(100);

System.out.println(pctDiscount);
```

I was expecting the program to output 75 but the output is:

> DoubleProperty [bound, invalid]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DoubleProperty` is a wrapper class. To get actual value

```
System.out.println(pctDiscount.getValue());
```

or

```
System.out.println(pctDiscount.get());
```